# Write a function that returns every other element of the list

Tags: ocaml

I want to write a function that can return every other element of the list like this ['a' ; 'b' ; 'c' ; 'd' ; 'e'] can return: ['a' ; 'c' ; 'e']
My function can use only with predefined functions List.hd, List.tl or List.length.
I wrote this but I think something wrong...

```
remove_half l =
  let rec rm_half n l =
    if l = [] then []
    else
      let fst = hd l in
      let rest = tl l in
      if n then fst :: (rm_half (not n) rest) 
      else (rm_half (not n) rest) 
  in
  rm_half true l;;
```

Comment: What exactly makes you think something is wrong? You're not describing an actual  problem here, just your assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, your code is missing a `let` and you haven't shown that you've opened `List`. If we fix those little things by adding the `let` and fully qualifying `List.hd` and `List.tl`:

```ml
utop # let remove_half l =
  let rec rm_half n l =
    if l = [] then []
    else
      let fst = List.hd l in
      let rest = List.tl l in
      if n then fst :: rm_half (not n) rest
      else rm_half (not n) rest
  in
  rm_half true l;;
val remove_half : 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>

utop # remove_half [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6];;
- : int list = [1; 3; 5]
```

Bingo. It works.

Now, this can be cleaned up using pattern-matching rather than `List.hd` and `List.tl`. The boolean is no longer necessary given that we can pattern match on the first two elements of a list with at least two elements.

```ml
let rec remove_half =
  function
  | x::_::xs -> x :: remove_half xs
  | lst -> lst
```

This technique can be applied using `List.hd` and `List.tl`.

```ml
let rec remove_half lst =
  if lst = [] || List.tl lst = [] then lst
  else 
    let x = List.hd lst in
    let xs = List.tl (List.tl lst) in
    x :: remove_half xs
```